# the actual mysql package appears to have a syntax error when used with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, syntax-error, unexpected-token

So i'm trying to use mysql with nodejs, and when I attempt to use it, I receive a syntax error that appears to originate within the MySQL package itself.

```
require('/usr/local/bin/mysql')
```

which returns the exception:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/bin/mysql:1
����

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: of course it will not work. You're trying to require non js file which is binary file for mysql client. just for fun do: `sudo cat /usr/local/bin/mysql`  if You'll see js source code as output come and hit me :)

Comment: if You want to connect to mysql use mysql npm package and try examples from it's page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: in those examples, they use require('mysql'), which I tried and it said "module not found," even though I've installed it. That's why I tried listing out the full path. Know why it would say "module not found"?

Comment: And actually if I set require() equal to a variable, I get: 
var = require('mysql')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='...

I'm very confused

Comment: please watch nodejs tutorials before guessing what and how to do, cause You're failing on basics of node and packaging

Comment: please watch at least these tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBNz5xF-Kx4, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L72fhGm1tfE, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN6Dx22cPRI

Comment: also use VS Code or WebStorm which will point to Your mistakes

Comment: MySQL (the DB) and the NodeJS [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package are entirely different things. The first is a DB server and the latter is a client library for JavaScript applications you use to connect to and interact with the former

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, guys. The solution was that I just had to install the latest version of the MySQL module from Github.

```
npm install mysqljs/mysql
```

forgot to add: I changed require('/usr/local/bin/mysql') back to require('mysql') after installing the latest version of MySQL as well.

Comment: No it wasn't. You had to correct the line `require('/usr/local/bin/mysql')`.

Comment: Well the "require('/usr/local/bin/mysql')" was an attempt to solve the problem of "module not found." So you're right, but changing that line only solves the problem after you import the latest version from github

Comment: As explained earlier in the comments, btw.

Answer (score 1):

1. init project:

```
npm init
```

2. install mysql package:

```
npm i --save mysql
```

3. connect to db ([manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)) :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'databasenamehere'
});
 
db.connect();
 
db.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', (error, rows, fields) => {
  console.log(rows);
});
```